# A More Perfect Union

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

To be a worthy nation here on earth, there are certain qualities that are essential.

1. It must establish its own unique Identity
2. The nation must be able to maintain Order
3. It must have checks and balances that are suitably Paired
4. Finally, it must, without a doubt, be...

   > **What?**

`1            2           3           4           5           6           7         8`
[image]
`9            10          11          12          13          14           15         16`
[image]
`17           18          19          20          21          22           23         24`
[image]
`25           26          27          28          29          30           31         32`
[image]
`33           34          35          36          37          38           39         40`
[image]
`41           42          43          44          45          46           47         48`
[image]

<sub>Any perceived omission(s) are intentional and necessary for the puzzle to work; they do not constitute a clue.</sub>

Comment: Is it intentional that the eighth number on each line is pushed to the next line?

Comment: That might only be on mobile; it does not appear that way on my computer @ArnaudMortier

Comment: I'm not on a mobile. And the zoom is set at 100%.

Comment: Not intentional, it may have to do with different monitors DPI settings, perhaps? Suffice it to say that the numbers are there only for reference: first picture on top row is #1, last on 2nd row is #16, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1. It must establish its own unique Identity`

> These are the lower 48 US states. some are rotated. I have **Identified** them in the reordered list below to avoid posting several 48-row lists.

`2. The nation must be able to maintain Order`

> I have rearranged them to reflect the **Order** they joined the Union:
> `list number - abbreviated state, union join number, color, rotation
>  19 - DE 1 black 180
>  18 - PA 2 white 180
>  12 - NJ 3 black 90
>  37 - GA 4 white 90
>  27 - CT 5 black 0
>  32 - MA 6 white 90
>  30 - MD 7 black 0
>  08 - SC 8 white 90
>  36 - NH 9 black 0
>  44 - VA 10 white 90
>  24 - NY 11 black 90
>  21 - NC 12 black 180
>  41 - RI 13 white 90
>  02 - VT 14 white 0
>  28 - KY 15 white 0
>  20 - TN 16 black 270
>  47 - OH 17 black 180
>  23 - LA 18 white 180
>  45 - IN 19 black 90
>  15 - MS 20 black 180
>  46 - IL 21 white 90
>  31 - AL 22 black 90
>  43 - ME 23 black 90
>  29 - MO 24 white 180
>  38 - AR 25 black 180
>  35 - MI 26 white 0
>  26 - FL 27 black 90
>  25 - TX 28 white 180
>  48 - IA 29 black 180
>  09 - WI 30 white 90
>  13 - CA 31 black 180
>  16 - MN 32 black 90
>  33 - OR 33 black 90
>  11 - KS 34 white 180
>  05 - WV 35 black 180
>  22 - NV 36 black 90
>  17 - NE 37 black 180
>  34 - CO 38 white 90
>  10 - ND 39 black 0
>  04 - SD 40 white 180
>  06 - MT 41 black 90
>  14 - WA 42 white 180
>  39 - ID 43 black 180
>  01 - WY 44 black 0
>  03 - UT 45 black 90
>  40 - OK 46 white 90
>  42 - NM 47 black 180
>  07 - AZ 48 black 90`

`3. It must have checks and balances that are suitably Paired`

> The original layout comes into play here. There are 6 rows of 8 - exactly 6 bytes of binary. Now, we see why AK and HI were omitted. The word **Paired** refers to this binary interpretation, with black as 0 and white as 1:
> `01010101
> 01001110
> 01001001
> 01010100
> 01000101
> 01000100`

`4. Finally, it must, without a doubt, be...`

> **United.**
>  That's the resulting word when translating the binary directly to text.

P.S. If anyone knows how to more cleanly show that list, feel free.

Comment: These are a couple of steps in the right direction, though I wouldn't worry too much about rotation; this was just a childish way to partially disguise what the images represented.

Comment: BTW, how did you (correctly) Identify WY and CO even though they have exactly the same shape? I guess you had a 50-50 chance, anyway. :)

Comment: Haha, I had left them as either/or in my scrap, but after looking closely at a map, I noticed that Colorado is just a bit wider that Wyoming. I'll be revisiting step 3 in a few minutes when I get to my desk

Comment: Well done, this is clever! I'll have to admit, with the way @Chowzen capitalized Identity, Order, and Paired, he had me off in the land of ring theory rather than this... +1 from me!

Comment: I have to stop reading my answer ... every time I look, I have to change something else hahaha

Comment: @Chowzen So the rotation is just a massive red herring?

Comment: Evidently. I suppose it's just wrench thrown at identifying the states.

Comment: @noedne As Matt says, it's to make the states a little harder to recognize.

Comment: @Chowzen Perhaps you could indicate this in the puzzle?

Comment: @noedne I don't think it's necessary. I think the steps as they are don't mention anything on orientation or rotation. I just fell for the red herring initially.

Comment: @noedne I personally wouldn't call it a red herring. It wasn't a *trick,* just a puzzle within the puzzle.

Comment: @Chowzen Fair. Is the updated answer correct?

Comment: @Matt Of course! Otherwise the coincidence would be cuh-razy!! :)